# Run powershell script when new user is created

Tags: powershell-extensions, user-management

So, I've been successful in creating a powershell script that modifies the MyToolbar to what we need based on the user's domain:

```
$ribbonCommands = "{1DDBC2B7-69B4-44A0-AAF9-895AB51B1F00}|{D87FDF3B-D203-4F2F-81A3-14D4701BAEF6}|{D4E9CE87-84D1-42E4-9B8B-55A99605EA82}|{EDA2F1DC-0412-45B2-9FDD-0700B03F28CB}|{1CC9896C-5D20-4439-8938-57B5BFB3734F}|{EDA2F1DC-0412-45B2-9FDD-0700B03F28CB}|{AE7CA3FB-770F-43A9-8BD9-B0E67090DD61}|{CF377B94-17EE-4D82-86B4-419A8B41901A}"

$user = Get-User -Filter "mydomain\*"

$user | ForEach-Object {  
    $prefix = "/"
    $username = $($_.Name)
    $suffix = "/Ribbon/My Strip"
    $registrykey = ${prefix} + ${username} + ${suffix}
    Write-Host $registrykey
    [Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Registry]::SetValue($registrykey, $ribbonCommands)
}
```

This works well for the bulk of users who are now on the system, however, what I want to do is run something like this but a) when a new user is created, and b) grabbing that username so that I can set the values of the MyToolbar for that given user when he or she is created.  Can this be done?  Does it require a processor of some kind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could consider running a script that fires with the `user:created` event.

Try the following:

## Step 1

Create a patch which tells SPE to run scripts for the Sitecore event.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:security="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/security/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement" security:require="Sitecore">
    <events>
      <event name="user:created">
        <handler type="Cognifide.PowerShell.Integrations.Tasks.ScriptedItemEventHandler, Cognifide.PowerShell" method="OnEvent" />
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

## Step 2

Create a new script containing your profile code. Optionally, add rules on the script to avoid unnecessary script executions (i.e. check for user role).

[image: Script Library]

Make sure that the script is nested under a folder structure like `[MODULE]/Event Handlers/User/Created/[SCRIPT_NAME]`. If you created a new module, be sure that it is marked enabled (doing so changes the icon).

```
$createdUser = $eventArgs.Parameters[0]
Write-Log "Created new user $($createdUser.Username)"
```

#### Update

In my experience, only the ID of an item based on the Large Button template will work.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to be missing something.  Where are you creating this "OnEvent" method?  Is this in a separate handler class I need to create in my project?

Comment: This is included with SPE.

Comment: Can you please join the slack channel to discuss further?