# Run Powershell script when an Item is being published

Tags: powershell-extensions, events

I'm trying to do implement some logic while a particular template item is getting published. To implement this logic I started exploring the Sitecore Powershell's Event Handlers. For the events like `item:added`, `item:copied` events I'm successfully able to get the output for the events, but for the Publish event like `publish:begin`, `publish:end` I'm not able to get any output from the result.

Below are the steps which I've followed to enable Sitecore Powershell events.

1. Created the Patch file for Spe.Event.config

```
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement" security:require="Sitecore">
    <events>
      <event name="publish:begin">
        <handler type="Spe.Integrations.Tasks.ScriptedItemEventHandler, Spe" method="OnEvent" />
      </event>
      <event name="publish:end">
        <handler type="Spe.Integrations.Tasks.ScriptedItemEventHandler, Spe" method="OnEvent" />
      </event>
      <event name="item:added">
        <handler type="Spe.Integrations.Tasks.ScriptedItemEventHandler, Spe" method="OnEvent" />
      </event>
      <event name="user:created">
        <handler type="Spe.Integrations.Tasks.ScriptedItemEventHandler, Spe" method="OnEvent" />
      </event>
      <event name="publish:startPublishing">
        <handler type="Spe.Integrations.Tasks.ScriptedItemEventHandler, Spe" method="OnEvent" />
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

2. Then I've created a module by following [these steps](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules), created Event Handlers with the help of [this article](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/event-handlers)
3. When I tried for the first time it was not successful and found out the solution [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19875/run-powershell-script-when-new-user-is-created) but when I try the same for Publish events it's not working
   [image: Sample Script]

Can some please assist me to figure out what mistake is being done here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the screenshot the Events module is not yet enabled. There is a checkbox.

Comment: @MichaelWest Upon checking the item I couldn't find the checkbox for enabling it. Can you please name the Field name? Also when I created the script for item:added event I haven't done for enabling it.

Comment: @MichaelWest Thanks for the information. Events are triggered after enabling the checkbox of the Events Module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Michael West, the enable checkbox is not checked. You need to activate it for the events to triggered.

Select the item `Events` and you will see a section named Module Activation. Check the enabled checkbox. Below is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Walid and Michael West. After enabling the checkbox my events are getting triggered.